# How to implement EIP-2612 permit in rust !ink

Tags: ink, smart-contract, features

I am trying to implement EIP-2612 permit functionality in my psp22 contract.
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/8a34d644aacf0f9f8f00815307fd7dd5da07655f/EIPS/eip-2612.md

But not sure how to do it.
Is there anybody have tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes, we are this is one of the [upcoming features of Openbrush](https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts/pull/109)
But, it's currently WIP, and we are waiting for merging [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1840), also is you want to use ecdsa approach you can check the following link [click](https://github.com/swanky-dapps/meta-transaction/blob/009a6784e77dee19bad2aeb2d34e632ad40abd5f/contracts/forwarder/lib.rs#L117)